# What commands are needed to get the distance from the car to the traffic light in MATLAB and SUMO

Tags: matlab, simulink, sumo

I have a route in SUMO which has a car and a traffic light, now I want to get the distance from the car to the traffic light and I wrote this code with the help of Traci4matlab library in Level-2 MATLAB S -Function block, now I run it , it gives a graph that doesn't look like reality. Please help me to get a command to detect the distance from the car to the traffic light.

I have a route in SUMO that has a car and a traffic light, now I want to get the distance from the car to the traffic light, and I wrote this code in Level-2 MATLAB S-Faunction, now when I run it, it gives a graph that is not similar to reality

```matlab
function mdlInitializeSizes(block)
     % Specify the number of input and output ports
     block.NumInputPorts = 1;
     block.NumOutputPorts = 2; % Additional output port for vehicle position
     % Specify the size and type of the input and output ports
     block.InputPort(1).Complexity = 'Real';
     block.InputPort(1).DataTypeID = 0; % double data type
     block.InputPort(1).Dimensions = []; % Allow any dimensions

     block.OutputPort(1).Complexity = 'Real';
     block.OutputPort(1).DataTypeID = 0; % double data type
     block.OutputPort(1).Dimensions = []; % Allow any dimensions
     block.OutputPort(1).SamplingMode = 'Sample'; % Set the frame status to known
     
     block.OutputPort(2).Complexity = 'Real'; % New output port for vehicle position
     block.OutputPort(2).DataTypeID = 0; % double data type
     block.OutputPort(2).Dimensions = []; % Allow any dimensions
     block.OutputPort(2).SamplingMode = 'Sample'; % Set the frame status to known
     % Set the sample time of the block (-1 means inherited)
     block.SampleTimes = [-1 0];
 
     % Register the mdlInitializeConditions, mdlUpdate, and mdlTerminate methods
     block.RegBlockMethod('InitializeConditions', @mdlInitializeConditions);
     block.RegBlockMethod('Update', @mdlUpdate);
     block.RegBlockMethod('Terminate', @mdlTerminate);
     block.RegBlockMethod('SetInputPortSamplingMode', @mdlSetInputPortSamplingMode); % Add this line
end
function mdlSetInputPortSamplingMode(block, portIdx, samplingMode)
    % Set the sampling mode of the first input port
    if portIdx == 1
        block.InputPort(portIdx).SamplingMode = samplingMode;
    end
end
function mdlInitializeConditions(~)
    % Initialize any necessary variables or states
    import traci.constants;
  
    % Start the SUMO simulation
    traci.start('sumo-gui -c ./config_file.sumocfg --start');
 
end
function mdlUpdate(block)
     % Get the input value (desired speed)
     if isnumeric(block.InputPort(1).Data)
         desiredspeed = double(block.InputPort(1).Data);
     else
         error('Input data is not a numeric value');
     end
     % Import Traci4Matlab constants
     import traci.constants;
     % Advance the simulation step
     traci.simulationStep();
     % Get the vehicle ID list
     vehicleID = traci.vehicle.getIDList();
     % Set the desired speed for the first vehicle
     traci.vehicle.setSpeed(char(vehicleID), desiredspeed);
     % Get the current speed of the first vehicle
     currentSpeed = traci.vehicle.getSpeed(char(vehicleID));
     % Get the position of the first vehicle
     position = traci.vehicle.getPosition(char(vehicleID));
     % Get the IDs of all traffic lights
     trafficLights = traci.trafficlights.getIDList();
     % Initialize variables for tracking the closest traffic light
     closestLightID = '';
     closestDistance = Inf;
     % Iterate over all traffic lights to find the closest one
     for i = 1:length(trafficLights)
         % Get the IDs of all lanes associated with the current traffic light
         lanes = traci.trafficlights.getControlledLanes(char(trafficLights(i)));
         % Iterate over all lanes to find the first lane's position
         for j = 1:length(lanes)
             % Get the position of the lane area corners
             laneAreaCorners = traci.lane.getShape(char(lanes(j)));
             % Convert lane area corners to numeric array
             laneAreaCorners = cell2mat(laneAreaCorners);
             % Calculate the average position of the lane
             lanePosition = mean(laneAreaCorners);
             % Calculate the distance between the vehicle and the current lane
             distance = norm(position - lanePosition);
             % Update the closest traffic light information if necessary
             if distance < closestDistance
                 closestDistance = distance;
                 closestLightID = char(trafficLights(i));
             end
             % Break the loop after finding the position of the first lane
             %break
         end
     end
     % Set the output values
     block.OutputPort(1).Data = double(currentSpeed(1)); % Assign the first element of the current Speed vector
     block.OutputPort(2).Data = double(closestDistance);
end
function mdlTerminate(~)
     % Clean up any resources, if necessary
     % Close the SUMO simulation
     traci.close();
end
```